# Tikz, can I have multigrids inside a table or matrix?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tikz-matrix, grids

I'm in charge of a mini-shop in my dorm, we need some accounting system. People pay with credits.

Usually it is done in paper, people take a beer and draw a line out from their name-row and the beer column. I'm getting tired of counting the lines, since people are really bad at drawing a straight line(especially when they are drunk), so I want to make a new layout where people crosses a small square off instead of drawing lines.

This is what i have right now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tabularx}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcounter{row}
\newcounter{col}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={210mm,297mm},
 left=10mm,
 right=10mm,
 top=10mm,
 bottom=10mm,
 }


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.27]
\begin{scope}[yshift=+50.8cm,xshift=+30.8cm]
\matrix(dict)[matrix of nodes, nodes={align=center,text width=3cm},
        row 1/.style={anchor=south},
        column 1/.style={nodes={text width=2.5cm,align=right,text height=0.57cm}}
    ]{
        ~ &  $b33r - 5kr$  & $Candy - 2kr $ & $b_1b_2$ & $b_1b_3$ & $b_2b_3$ & $b_1b_2b_3$\\ \hline
        Pilliam \\ \cline{1-2}
        Rilliam \\ \cline{1-2}
        Tilliam \\ \cline{1-2}
        Nilliam \\ \cline{1-2}
        Milliam \\ \cline{1-2}
        Qilliam \\ \cline{1-2}
        Pilliam \\ \cline{1-2}
        Rilliam \\ \cline{1-2}
        Tilliam \\ \cline{1-2}
        Nilliam \\ \cline{1-2}
        Milliam \\ \cline{1-2}
        William \\ \cline{1-2}
        William \\ \cline{1-2}
        William \\ \cline{1-2}
        William \\ \cline{1-2}
        William \\ \cline{1-2}
        Qilliam \\ \cline{1-2}
        Qilliam \\ \cline{1-2}
        William \\ \cline{1-2}
        William \\ \cline{1-2}
        William \\ \cline{1-2}
        Pilliam \\ \cline{1-2}
        Rilliam \\ \cline{1-2}
        Tilliam \\ \cline{1-2}
        Nilliam \\ \cline{1-2}
        Milliam \\ \cline{1-2}
        William \\ \cline{1-2}
        William \\ \cline{1-2}
        William \\ \cline{1-2}
        William \\ \cline{1-2}
        William \\ \cline{1-2}
        William \\ \cline{1-2}
        William \\
    }; 
    \end{scope}
    %\draw(dict-1-1.south west)--(dict-1-8.south east);
    \draw(dict-1-1.north east)--(dict-33-1.south east);
    \draw(dict-1-2.north east)--(dict-1-2.south east);
    \draw(dict-1-3.north east)--(dict-1-3.south east);

    %[xshift=-15.9cm,yshift=-28.8cm]

    \begin{scope}
  \draw (0, 0) grid (60, 99);
    \draw[very thick, scale=3] (0, 0) grid (20, 33);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

There are nine small squares inside a big square, so I know when a big square is crossed, it counts as nine.

The problem is the row lines don't matches the grid lines.

Please help and feel free to make something that is more awesome than mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't quite take the approach you do.  But I think this will give you the result you want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

%% create a box to save the grid in (saves some time since 
%% the grid won't have to be recreated for each cell).     
\def\aeunit{0.25cm}
\newsavebox\tictactoebox
\begin{lrbox}\tictactoebox
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=\aeunit-0.4pt/3,
                      y=\aeunit-0.4pt/3,
                      every node/.style={outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=\aeunit-0.4pt},
                      baseline={($(current bounding box.center)+(0,-\aeunit/2)$)},
                     ]
    \draw    (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
    \foreach \myn in {0,1,...,3}
      {    \draw (0,\myn) -- (3,\myn); }
    \foreach \myn in {0,1,...,3}
      {    \draw (\myn,0) -- (\myn,3); }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{lrbox}

%% draw the extended vertical lines between marked columns
%% #1 column where to draw vertical line                  
\newcommand\aeDrawBorderAt[1]{%%
  \coordinate (B/C#1/top) at (R1/C#1);
  \coordinate (B/C#1/bot) at (R\aeMaxRowCount/C#1|-R\aeMaxRowCount/bot);
  \draw[blue,line width=0.6pt]
    (B/C#1/top)
    ++
    (0,4pt+\baselineskip)
    --
    (B/C#1/bot);
  }

%% label the columns              
%% #1 left column number          
%% #2 right column number         
%% #3 content for labeling columns
\newcommand\aeLabelColumns[3]{%%
  \path (R1/C#1) -- (R1/C#2) node[midway,above,yshift=0pt] {#3};
  \aeDrawBorderAt{#1}
  \aeDrawBorderAt{#2}
}

%% #1 = number of columns to create
%% #2 = list of names              
\newcommand\aebuildtable[2]{%%
  \foreach \myn [count=\mycnt] in {#2}
  {
    %% previous value 
    \pgfmathsetmacro\myp{int(\mycnt-1)}
    %% set nodes that fix each row
    \ifnum\mycnt=1\relax
      \coordinate (R\mycnt) at (0,\mycnt-1);
    \else                   
      \coordinate (R\mycnt) at (R\myp/bot);
    \fi
    %% a coordinate for the bottom of each row
    \coordinate (R\mycnt/bot)  at ($(R\mycnt)+(0,-3*\aeunit)$);
    %% node for name:
    \node[anchor=north east,outer sep=0pt] (N\mycnt) at ($(R\mycnt)+(-4pt,-\aeunit/2)$) {\myn};
    \foreach \mycol in {0,...,#1}
    {
      \coordinate (R\mycnt/C\mycol) at ($(R\mycnt)+({\mycol*(\aeunit*3)},0)$);
      \node[outer sep=0pt,
            inner sep=0pt,
            anchor=north west,]  
           at (R\mycnt/C\mycol.north west) {\usebox\tictactoebox};
    }
    \xdef\aeMaxRowCount{\mycnt}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \aebuildtable{10}{Mary,Jane,Scott,William,Todd}

  \aeLabelColumns{0}{4}{$b33r-5kr$}
  \aeLabelColumns{4}{8}{$Candy-2kr$}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]